# How to redirect all the www requests to non www with query params

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I am trying to redirect all the www URLs to non-www URLs

from :

```
1. http://example.com/web-url
2. http://www.example.com/web-url
3. https://www.example.com/web-url
```

to :

```
https://example.com/web-url
```

I have used the configuration as below.

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

By the above, all seems to be okay, but the 3rd option is not working as expected. The issue is 
`https://www.example.com/web-url` is redirected to `https://example.com/index.php`

**Can anyone tell me what is the issue with my configuration?**

Comment: You need to do your external redirecting, before the internal rewrites.

Comment: @CBroe and how can I do that?

Comment: By changing the _order_ of those lines in your .htaccess file …

Comment: @CBroe thanks man it worked. Changing the order of the above rules worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the order of the rules worked as expected.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```